# Puppeteer: Why is object returning undefined in page.evaluate function?

Tags: node.js, object, undefined, puppeteer

I've been trying to use puppeteer to scrape Twitch.

The idea for this program is to get the icon, username, & thumbnail of every stream in (for example) the category 'Just Chatting' in the 1st page.
I think my main code is working, but the object I'm trying to return (properties) is being returned as undefined.

I tried adding await behind my console.log in the function log(), and I also searched it up on here and read that the values returned from evaluate function have to be json serializeable, which I believe do include the strings which the object would have. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```js
let properties = { icon: [], user: [], img: [], link: [] };
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
let elements = {
  'https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Just%20Chatting': [
    'img[class="InjectLayout-sc-588ddc-0.iyfkau.tw-image.tw-image-avatar"]',
    'a[class="ScCoreLink-udwpw5-0.cxXSPs.tw-link"]',
    'img[class="tw-image"]',
  ],
};
async function scrapeStreams() {
  console.log('scrape started');
  try {
    console.log('try started');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.goto(Object.keys(elements)[0], { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.evaluate(
      (properties, elements) => {
        for ([key, value] of Object.entries(elements)) {
          if ((key = Object.keys(elements)[0])) {
            value.forEach((element) => {
              if ((element = Object.values(elements)[0])) {
                el = document.querySelector(element);
                for (let val in el) {
                  datatype = val.src;
                  Object.values(properties)[0].push(datatype);
                }
              } else if ((element = Object.values(elements)[1])) {
                el = document.querySelector(element);
                for (let val in el) {
                  datatype = val.innerHTML;
                  Object.values(properties)[1].push(datatype);
                }
              } else if ((element = Object.values(elements)[2])) {
                el = document.querySelector(element);
                for (let val in el) {
                  datatype = val.src;
                  Object.values(properties)[2].push(datatype);
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }

        return properties;
      },
      properties,
      elements
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('THIS IS THE ERROR: ' + error);
  }
}

async function log() {
  let properties = await scrapeStreams();
  console.log(properties);
}

log();
```

Comment: Can you add any of the debugging or console.log output?  Something that shows the work you've done to this point, that may also help indicate where the problem may live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Variables inside and outside of the function argument of `page.evaluate()` are not the same: they are copied while transferred between Node.js and browser contexts. So while you change `properties` inside `page.evaluate()`, the `properties` outside remains unchanged. While you use `return properties;` inside `page.evaluate()`, you are not save the returned value.
2. You forget to return value in `scrapeStreams()`.

However, it seems there are some other issues in your code (many `null` are returned), but you may use another question for them.

```js
// ...
    // FIXED:
    properties = await page.evaluate(
// ...
    // FIXED:
    return properties;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('THIS IS THE ERROR: ' + error);
  }
}
// ...
```